# Is there a simpler way for me to decide who should initiate a WebRTC offer?

Tags: webrtc

In the tutorial I'm following, we generate a unique number assigned to each client, and based on whoever's number is smaller, that one sends the WebRTC initial offer.

This is confusing in a way that I'm not quite sure what alternatives would work. Could someone explain the possible ways of doing this? Is there any "cleaner" or "simpler" way than to generate a unique number ID on the server and informing both clients what their number is and the number of the client they're trying to connect to, all in order to decide who should initiate an offer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any mechanism you want, but numbers *are* rather simple. You could also explicitly assign "roles" like "caller" and "callee", which has about the same effect. In my application I'm using the [WAMP protocol](http://wamp-proto.org) for signalling, in which each client gets a session id assigned automatically as part of the protocol; that makes for a very "natural" smaller-session-number-initiates-call mechanism (in my app peers signal a `ready` event, so they know each other's session number anyway). Simply *somebody* needs to decide who goes first; the server is in a natural position to decide that either by assigning numbers or roles or whatever else you want.